# How do I convert result of a Query directly to my data object in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a dataobject like

```
class DocInfo
{
String docId;
String corrId;
String familyId;
}
```

This maps to a database table. 
I'm using a combination of session factory and criteria to execute my query in hibernate which returns the rows that match the query on docId.

```
Query q = getCurrentSession().createQuery("from DocInfo item where item.docId = :docId");
        q.setString("docId", docId);
        return q;
```

Is there a way to directly create a data object out of the results of a query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can get a list of DocInfo using q.list()

```
List<DocInfo> docInfoList = q.list();
return docInfoList;
```

Answer (score 1):

`Query.list()` will execute the query and return a `List` of `DocInfo` results.